# CSS grouping child elements under parent

Tags: css, css-selectors

is it possible to avoid this repetitive css declaration?

Somehow group `table th` and `table td` under just one `weather-component`

```
weather-component table th, 
weather-component table td {
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

Something like...

```
weather-component (table th, table td) {
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at SASS or LESS.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible in CSS. But for example in LESS, you could write that as

```
.weather-component table {
   th, td {
    text-align: center !important;
  }
}
```